# Import data from Excel into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, oledbconnection

I want to import an Excel file into SQL Server but I face an error.

My code:

```
create table test
(
    AccountNumber varchar(50),  
    AccountName varchar(50),
    ParentAccountNumber varchar(50)

)

select * 
into test 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Error:

> Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Note:

- Excel version : 2007
- SQL Server version : 2012

Comment: Generally this means either the driver is not installed or only the 32bit version is installed and your have 64 bit SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

If you are not aware of writing scripts, you can do it by wizard itself.

1. Right click the DB name you want to import your excel file into. select Task-> Import.
2. New wizard will open and select the source as Microsoft excel and destination as Sql server, and give the authentication.
3. Rest all are self expainable.
4. You can preview the data before you import and you can control the columns you want to import.
5. Atlast click on finish to run the package.
6. Will acknowledge you for the successfull import.

Comment: i know this way but i prefer to write script for it . anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below code:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO

select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',   
'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES',   
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Make sure your excel sheet is closed when you are running this code.

Comment: Are you sure? The provider in that string is ACE, so isn't your error about ACE this time (not Microsoft.Jet)

Comment: ACE did work in my case. I think user's machine might be missing the OLEDB component that connects SSMS with excel.

Comment: i got this error : OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: can you try to save the file on some shared drive and then access it from there?

Comment: also check if both the SQL Server and Excel are of same version. One of them might be 32 bit and other is 64 bit and in this case, the drivers do cause compatibility issues. Visit the below url for more details:

[link](http://leansoftware.net/en-us/help/excel-database-tasks/worked-examples/loading-data/how-to-import-excel-spreadsheet-to-sql-server-data.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this after table creation,

```
INSERT INTO test (AccountNumber , AccountName , ParentAccountNumber)
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
      'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES',
      'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```